# How stop a for loop when parsing a JSONArray for nameless JSONObject?

Tags: android, json, parsing, for-loop

I want to parse a `JSONArray` that contains `JSONObject`s that have no names and whose (`index` int) positions within the array changes every week or so.  I have attempted to parse a particular `Object` by it's attributes, but my parser only returns the last Object in the array.

How can i stop my loop when it reaches the object i want to parse and determine the int index of the object for further parsing.

```
try {
        JSONArray jArray = JSONthing.getJSONfromURL("http://something.com");
        String attributeiwant = "abc";
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject alpha = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String attributeparsed = alpha.getString("widget");
            if (attributeparsed == attributeiwant) {
                //determine int index of object, so i can parse other attributes
                //from same object          

            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+ e.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **String.equals** for comparing  Strings instead of **==**

```
try {
        JSONArray jArray = JSONthing.getJSONfromURL("http://something.com");
        String attributeiwant = "abc";
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject alpha = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String attributeparsed = alpha.getString("widget");
            if (attributeparsed.equals(attributeiwant)) {
                //determine int index of object, so i can parse other attributes
                //from same object          
                // Get data from JsonObject
                break;
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+ e.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

use break; statement to break the loop, change your code to following:

```
int i = 0;

try {
        JSONArray jArray = JSONthing.getJSONfromURL("http://something.com");
        String attributeiwant = "abc";
        for (; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject alpha = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String attributeparsed = alpha.getString("widget");
            if (attributeparsed.equals(attributeiwant)) {
                //determine int index of object, so i can parse other attributes
                //from same object          
                break;
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+ e.toString());
        }

if(i<jArray.length())
{
   //item found, use i as index of object.
}
else
   //item not found.
```